# Accidentally installed OpenWRT Upgrade image on TP-Link and now Cannot Telnet

Tags: openwrt

I wanted to convert my TP-Link WR841N into an Openflow switch for which I followed the guide at kickstartSDN.com

Since there was no instruction on which image to download, I accidentally upgraded router with the OpenWRT upgrade image and now I cannot telnet 192.168.1.1 into my router. I have enabled telnet and have also tried telnet through PuTTy. Cannot connect. I can, however, SSH into the device. When I do that I cannot find OpenFlow in the /lib which comes with OpenWRT.

Please help, should I revert back to stock firmware of TP-Link? What should I do?

Comment: I assume you have verified the image you applied to your router actually supports your router?

Comment: yes, the image does support my router

Answer (score 3):

TP-Link WR841N router supports flash from TFTP server.

If you want to revert, download latest firmware for your router with correct HW revision from TP-Link website. Then download some TFTP server. For example you can use http://tftpd32.jounin.net/.

Run TFTP server in directory with firmware file (or in tftpd32 you can browse this dir).

Then you need to rename firmware .bin file to `wr841nv11_tp_recovery.bin`. This is file name valid for router with HW revision 11.X. If you have any other HW revision replace v11 with your revision number. For example for HW revision 10.1 it is `wr841nv10_tp_recovery.bin`.

Next step is unconnect all devices from router and connect just computer with TFTP server into any lan port and manually set on this computer IP address to 192.168.0.66 with mask 255.255.255.0.

Then power off your router (by button next to power cable) then power on, when red led turn on press and hold `WPS/RESET` button until red led turn off. After that router will request TFTP server on your computer for `wr841nv11_tp_recovery.bin` and flash them. Wait... and Wait... and Wait... After router reboot (signalized by red led) flashing is done and you can set on your computer IP address to getting by DHCP server. Now you can access standard web interface on default gateway address (usually 192.168.0.1).

Comment: I got the firmware back using the official OpenWRT guide. Grateful for you answer anyways. The problem is, even after installing the correct firmware from OpenWRT, it does not have the lib/openflow directory that I want and thus I have to revert back to stock firmware again to build my custom image.

Comment: Worked for my bricked TP-LINK WR841n v11.1, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Luci Web interface http://TPLIN-IP-ADDRESS , login (with root), and select choose the System menu, "Backup/Flash firmware", "Restore backup".

There are also options to recover it via TFTP described here: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd

Comment: The web interface was not working, I went back to original firmware. Now will be building my custom image for adding it in.